# Which grid-like layout in Android for Remote Control interface?

Tags: android, layout, button, size, grid-layout

I want to draw a TV remote interface on an Android Activity screen. But I don't succeed in getting the buttons to the right places. Because I'm using a grid internally to init the buttons (programmatically by the way) I thought using a GridLayout and placing the buttons as subviews should be the best way. (I was trying it with TableLayout before, but I couldn't find out how to init a button that has a height going over two or more TableRows.)

But the GridLayout class automatically resets all buttons when I change the size of one button, as a result my view looks pretty bad. Is there a way to set the exact places where my buttons should be using a GridLayout? Or would you recommend another type of Layout?

This is what I expect the whole thing to look like at the end (except the "Endgeräte auswählen" button):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try relative layout :

```
RelativeLayout Main = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    Main.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);

    Button but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("BTN");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("BTN 2");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Center");
    but.setId(998900);
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("below");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, 998900);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Center above");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, 998900);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Center left");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 998900);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Center right");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 998900);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    but = new Button(this);
    but.setText("Bottom");
    but.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    viewParamsCenter = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    viewParamsCenter.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    but.setLayoutParams(viewParamsCenter);
    Main.addView(but);

    RelativeLayout Main_SUPER = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
    Main_SUPER.addView(Main);
```